# Does changing the image src do an http request?

Tags: jquery, caching

I have the below images that are loaded at the top of the page

```
<img id="hidden-image1" style="display: none;" src="/1392655380-4.png">
<img id="hidden-image2" style="display: none;" src="/1392655401-7.png">
```

Other image:

```
<img id="img1" style="display: none;" src="/def.png">
```

what i do in jquery is

```
if(true){
    $('#img1').attr("src", $('#hidden-image1').attr("src"));
}else{
    $('#img1').attr("src", $('#hidden-image2').attr("src"));
}
```

will the jquery result in rerequesting the image? if so how can i prevent that?

what I am trying to do is some sort of caching

Comment: It won't cache IMO. It will still make a server trip to fetch the `src` of your hidden images.

Comment: is it possible to not rerequesting the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is something like this:

```
$('#hidden-image1').insertBefore($('#some-element'));
$('#hidden-image2').insertBefore($('#some-other-element'));
```

and that did the trick.